# Animate move and scale of image UIButton

Tags: iphone, uiimageview, uiimage, uibutton

I want it to be animated so I'm using `[UIView beginAnimations]`

I've tried animating using `button.imageView.frame` (with image set as imageView) but it only animates the position, the image doesn't get scaled down at all.

using `hateButton.frame` (when image is set as backgroundImage), the backgroundImage gets scaled down but it's not animated.

How do I animate-scale a UIButton image?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I could achieve this using Quartz 2D:

```
// move anchor point without moving frame
CGRect oldFrame = hateButton.frame;
hateButton.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0, 1); // bottom left
hateButton.frame = oldFrame;

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];  
CGAffineTransform newTransform;
newTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.8, 0.8);
hateButton.transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(newTransform, 0, -160);
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Make sure you import Quartz2D too:

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

Comment: You could apply the transform directly to the button.imageView by setting button.imageView.transform to your CGAffineTransform.

Comment: I decided to use an UIImageView instead and could thus use the normal animatable frame. Then on top I put an invisible UIButton.

Answer (score 5):

You can call `layoutIfNeeded` between `[UIView beginAnimations]` and `[UIView commintAnimations]` or with `[UIView animateWithDuration]`.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3f animations:^{
    self.myButton.frame = aFrame;    
    [self.myButton layoutIfNeeded];
 }];
```